# Issue with MediaPlayer and android 4.4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a Streaming Video App. Video start in 3-5 seconds in android 4.0-4.3 but I don't know what happen in Android 4.4+ start is more than 20 sec long. Any fix or hack?

```
private void playVideo(String url) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {

        // Create a new media player and set the listeners
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),    PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mOnVideoSizeChangedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mOnBufferingUpdateListener);
        //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoPath2);
        //wifiLock.acquire();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mVideoSurfaceViewHolder);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

- `prepareAsync()` is called
- then in 2 sec `onPrepare()` callback
  but video start in more than 20 sec in 4.4. In android 4.3 start in 3 sec...

Bug?? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62304
any fix/hack?

Comment: Based on your shared information: no!